# Script not executing in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, udf

Everytime I execute my script it just echos everything in my script and never executes it. It forms numbers on the side for the lines of code then it never lets me get out of it I have to restart all over again to try again. Here is an the code it does it after.

```
-- 1

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ZIP_CODE_SALES(zip_in IN VARCHAR)
  RETURN FLOAT
IS
  totalSales FLOAT;
BEGIN
  SELECT SUM(S.gross_sale_price) INTO totalSales
  FROM SALE S JOIN CUSTOMER C
  ON S.cust_ID = C.cust_ID
  GROUP BY C.zip_code 
  HAVING C.zip_code = zip_in;   
  RETURN totalSales;
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add hadd a slash`/` after the `end;` to ensure the DML in the buffer is executed.

> ```
> END;
> /
> ```